# Having a Gradient go Across Two Side by Side Divs React

Tags: html, css, jsx

As for setting up two divs to be side by side, I think I understand that part. I'm just trying to have a CSS gradient go across the two divs uninterrupted along the middle split.  I'm hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve like complex coloring.

What I tried doing is setting the background color in a parent div, and not have a color set for the two side by side child divs.

```
function Footer() {
    return (
        <div className="box">
            <div className="leftbox">
                <Logo />
            </div>
            <div className="rightbox">
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
.box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,139,1) 100%);
  
}

.leftbox { 
  float:left;  
  width:50%; 
  height:100%; 
  clear: none;
} 

.rightbox{ 
  float:right; 
  width:50%; 
  height:100%; 
  clear: none;
}
```

What happens with this is that only the left div is colored.  Which makes me think I'm not doing this whole parent/child div thing correctly hahaha.  So that's the problem, I'm trying to have that background under "box" span across both divs without being interrupted in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens with this is that only the left div is colored. Which makes me think I'm not doing this whole parent/child div thing correctly

The bug has to be elsewhere - my guess `<Logo />` which breaks absolutely valid css.
As you are a beginner, a word of advice - don't use `float` and don't even touch `flex`, firstly - you don't need them, secondly they have more side effects than they're worth.

Snippet - without `float`, without redundancy, without troubles. Use `border`s in production - to see what you've done :)

```css
body{
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
.blue, .green{
margin: 2vh 0;
padding: 0;
}
.blue{
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(2,0,36), rgba(0,0,139));
border: 1px solid red;
}
.green{
background: linear-gradient(to left, #cf8, #193);
border: 1px solid black;
}
.blue div, .green div{
height: 100%;
width: 49%;     /* kind of insurance - some space for weird devices and browsers */
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<div><img src="blue.jpg" alt="one"></div>
<div>two</div>
</div>

<div class="green">
<div>three</div>
<div>four</div>
</div>
```

Almost forgot - use [Validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/) w3c, like the masters do.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot for making it a code snippet as well, so I could see what this exact code did.  And yeah you were right about <Logo />, I was already coloring that component and that's the only reason it had any color beforehand.